# mPDF don't wrap text on a new page

Tags: php, mpdf

I use mPDF, there is a generated list on the page, which, having reached the end of the page, goes to a new one.

But I need to print only one page, and the data that goes to the new page needs to be changed to "..." and not transferred to another page.
how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be multiple solutions to your problem, but I have one in mind.

Start counting lines in your generated list and stop outputting content when it reached a specific number.

Let's say you have pdf header with your company logo, then there is a space for roughly 30 lines of data from your list before it will fill the remaining space.

Then what you need to do is instead let your loop wild that is outputting data until finished, count and upon reaching the number break the loop.

since you do not have any code I would assume you have data like this:

```
$n = 0;
$html = '';
$single_line_limit = 300;
foreach ( $data as $line )
{
  $n++;

  // if line is too long, it takes 2 linebreaks
  if ( strlen($line) >= $single_line_limit  )
    $n++;

  // if line is even longer, it takes 3 linebreaks
  if ( strlen($line) >= ($single_line_limit * 2) )
    $n++;

  if ( $n >= 30 )
    break;

  $html .= '<div class="line">'.$line.'</div>';
    
}

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
```

30 line is a number from my head, you would have to find that number from experiments.. as its based on the font and font size you have set for your pdf.

**Edit:** added example how you can calculate line and based on that you can (roughly) know that it will take more than one line.

Again, there is probably more elegant ways to accomplish this, but this is how I would approach this.

Comment: Yes, I thought to count the lines, but there is a problem, if the processed line is too long and does not fit in one line, then we see two or three lines in the output.
The total is conditionally 10 processed lines and from 10 to 20 (maybe more) in the output, yes, we can calculate the maximum possible number of additional lines and, for safety, process fewer lines.
But then we don't get all possible line outputs until the end of the page, but only a certain number of lines.
So far, this is a working method.

Comment: I'm wondering if it's possible using mPDF or something else to find the end of the page and cut off the text on it.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need data worth of only 1 page? is it something like preview? and page #2 and more are paid? Because mpdf handles page breaking well,  and you can insert pagebreaks where you want them. Anyway, in case you have multiple lines.. one way to solve it - is start counting characters.. yeah! :) I am editing my answer so you could see an example

Comment: Thanks, I added a character count to my code, it turned out quite well and, most importantly, it works!)

Comment: Glad that it worked well for you. Quite often there's a simple solution to every problem :)